# c++ address family not supported by protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I write a method, that creates a socket, connect it to the endpoint, and then returns its descriptor:

```
static int open_socket(const char* host, unsigned short port)
        {
            #ifdef USE_IPV4
            struct hostent* _hostent;
            struct sockaddr_in _sockaddr_in;

            // Variables
            size_t sockaddr_len;
            int sock_family;
            int sock_type;
            int sock_protocol;
            int sockfd;

            _hostent = gethostbyname(host);
            if (_hostent == (struct hostent*) 0)
            {
                // Not Found
            }

            _sockaddr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sock_family = AF_INET;
            sock_type = SOCK_STREAM;
            sock_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
            sockaddr_len = sizeof(_sockaddr_in);
            (void*) memmove(&_sockaddr_in, _hostent->h_addr, _hostent->h_length);
            _sockaddr_in.sin_port = htons(port);

            // Now create socket
            sockfd = socket(sock_family, sock_type, sock_protocol);
            if (sockfd < 0)
            {
                // "Internal Error"
            }
            if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &_sockaddr_in, sockaddr_len) < 0)
            {
                std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                std::cerr << "Endpoint is unavailable" << std::endl;
                return 0;
                // "Unavailable"
            }

            return sockfd;

            #endif
        }
```

The error occures when i try  to connect socket. strerror(errno) returns "Address family not supported by  protocol". I cannot figure out why it happens, because in other samples AF_INET fine works with IPPROTO_TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the address in `sockaddr_in::sin_addr` instead.  You are overwriting the entire struct (starting from the `sin_family`) when you call `memmove(&_sockaddr_in, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks! It was a very stupid question. I just used: memcpy(&_sockaddr_in.sin_addr, _hostent->h_addr, _hostent->h_length);

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `gethostbyname()` at all, as it is deprecated.  Use `getaddrinfo()` instead, and let it return a fully formatted `sockaddr_in` for you.